# Best way to recover a photo library when it is incompatible with current os

Tags: mac, imac, photos, data-recovery, compatibility

I’d like to delve deeper into recovering a Photos library.  The originals are very easy to get back.  How/where is stuff like added locations and facial recognition/people data stored, and now pets. I’ve done a ton of work that I’d really like back.

Thus I’d like to know what all the package contents are. Which files/folders/contents, besides originals/masters can be copied between libraries?  Which ones contain data related to modifications and augmentation of originals?  Are system changes resulting in compatibility issues interlaced with data (I really hope not)?

The Sonoma update messed up my iMac, which became non-functional and the end result was a clean install, reverting back to Ventura via Catalina. It is stable again and I’ve restored everything but Photos.

If Apple isn’t going to provide compatibility, I want to document a process for myself to know I can get back all my stuff just in case this happens again. Too much work in Photos to lose it.

So what is that process for photos?
Step one, get image files you loaded.
Next?

Comment: Do you have iCloud Photo Library enabled?

Comment: Why don't you have backups of the library?  iCloud Photo Library isn't a backup and Apple tells you that it isn't a backup.

Comment: If the library changed format in any way between Ventura & Sonoma, then to get it back you need a backup from *before* the update. Apple have never provided a way to go 'downhill'.

Comment: No backup prior to Sonoma because I'm busy starting a new job and didn't know Sonoma would be such a gdfm.

Comment: 90? of people DON'T backup, EVER.  I think that is being generous.  Probably closer to 95%. So not having a daily backup routine is closer to normal

Comment: Anyone out there with database experience and in depth knowledge of the library package contents?

Comment: Having data you can't afford to loose but not making backups of it seems to be a bad idea in general. If your statistics are correct, 97% of people will loose data sooner or later. But anyway: Do you have iCloud Photo Library enabled? Or would enabling it on a Mac running Sonoma, having it sync all photos, and then syncing them to the Mac running Ventura be an option?

Comment: That kind of a response isn't helpful.  Next time life interferes with you doing a backup and you being psychic to know exactly when apple updates are going to be done, I'll send you a copy of this message.

Comment: Library recovered from a helpful comment and auto updates turned off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Library is an iCloud Photos lib you can download a fresh copy while booted to the earlier OS.

Another little known way is to open the Photos Library in the older OS while holding command plus option keys. This will start a lengthy repair process at the end of which the incompatible library will open in the older OS. I didn’t believe this when first told about it but it works.

Comment: Repair worked!  Thank you so much.  I've repaired the library while inside photos.  I have notes somewhere.  Not sure if it is the same process.

Comment: Somewhere else, someone said since the facial recognition is proprietary, that "meta data" isn't exported with the files.  That alone should have told me that it is probably hidden in one of the databases.  An apple engineer can probably extract the info and get it into a usable format to go into a new table and still have the library function but they won't do it.

Comment: I'm going to slowly start reworking my library so the recognition is done and then I store the info where it will export.  That was the suggested rework so keep your faces even though Apple identifies them.

Answer (score -1):

Unmodified original versions of all photos and videos are stored in the Originals folder. You can access this folder by right-clicking the Photos library and selecting Show Package Contents. Details of all edits, metadata (e.g. locations, dates, time), face recognition etc. are stored in Photos.sqlite database. For more details see [Inside and Out of Photos for Mac](https://appinitio.medium.com/hey-mac-user-where-are-your-photos-d9056ee4963e).

Comment: How does this (or the linked article) address the problem described in the question and allow the OP to downgrade the photo library?

Comment: So, do you know if the database referred to where it stores the facial recognition info going to be compatible? If I copied in the originals which I know works, I can try copying that one additional piece.  If they have changed the name might be hooped, or other db characteristics might affect it.  Extra copies and test different things! Thanks for that article.  I think I could also try photo req on a couple of pictures then replace the file it creates, assuming it has the same name.  Thanks!

Comment: Facial recognition data isn't in one place. In photos.sqlite database, tables such as ZDETECTEDFACE, ZFACECROP, ZADDITIONASSETATTRIBUTES etc. store relevant info.